# What's the difference between setupFiles and setupTestFrameworkScriptFile

Tags: jestjs

I read the document and got confused on the difference between these two. I know codes in setupFiles would be executed before codes in setupTestFrameworkScriptFile. What else differences do they have?

I guess codes in these two would be executed before each test. Does that mean if I have 10 it(); they are executed 10 times?

Comment: Note: setupTestFrameworkScriptFile is deprecated in favor of setupFilesAfterEnv, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` and `setupFiles` are executed before each file containing tests. If you have 10 tests in one file - no mater how many `describe`'s - it will run once. If in 2 separate files - it will run twice.

In both `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` and `setupFiles` you can initiate globals, like this:
`global.MY_GLOBAL = 42`

`setupFiles` run before test framework is installed in the environment.

In `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` you have also access to installed test environment, methods like `describe`, `expect` and other globals. You can for example add your custom matchers there:

```
expect.extend({
  toHaveLength(received, argument) {
    // ...
  }
})
```

... or set a new maximum timeout interval:
`jest.setTimeout(12000)`